# AngularJS - request inside $timeout

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, request, timeout

I want to make an autocomplete functionality using Angular Material `<md-chips>`. 
I have the following html:

```
     <md-chips ng-model="programs" md-require-match="true">
         <md-autocomplete
             md-selected-item="selectedItem"
             md-search-text="searchText"
             md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
             md-item-text="item.name"
             placeholder="Target programs"
             md-autoselect="true">
             <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
        </md-autocomplete>  
        <md-chip-template>
           <span>
             <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
           </span>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
```

and the method `querySearch`:

```
                // Search for programs
                scope.querySearch = function(query) {
                    if (typeof pauseMonitor !== 'undefined') {
                        $timeout.cancel(pauseMonitor); 
                    }

                    pauseMonitor = $timeout(function() {
                        Programs.getQuery(query)
                        .then(function(data){
                            return data.data.campaigns;
                        });
                    }, 250);
                };
```

My problem is that the method finds good matches after I type in the autocomplete input but the browser doesn't show them.  I think that it might be because of the request but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you forgot to return the result, you return `data.data.campaings` but you have to return the promise also.

You can try this:

```
// Search for programs
scope.querySearch = function(query) {
    if (typeof pauseMonitor !== 'undefined') {
        $timeout.cancel(pauseMonitor); 
    }

    pauseMonitor = $timeout(function() {
        return Programs.getQuery(query)
        .then(function(data){
            return data.data.campaigns;
        });
    }, 250);
    return pauseMontitor;
};
```